# How to make nautilus open all partitions in same window instead of another windows.

Tags: nautilus, launcher

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I've 3 partitions

1. Filesystem
2. Data1
3. Data2

Suppose I open ~/home/vivek/Desktop and then go to Data1 partition, at that time there another icons in unity launcher for this partition.

Is there any way to make nautilus to not open in another window?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is made by design in the new Nautilus version in 16.04.

If you click on another partition a new window is opened. It is really annoying.

A workaround for this is to make permanent mounts for these partitions in `fstab` and make bookmarks for the mount points in Nautilus, or make symlinks to the Home folder.

Then you will be opening these partitions as regular directories in the same window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am trying to use Nemo. But nautilus search is fast.

Answer (score 0):

In your first Nautilus window, enter a **control-t** (or choose **New Tab** from the File menu), and direct the new tab to whatever directory you'd like to see.